# AWS StepFunction with Invoke Child Workflow state using cloud formation giving in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to create a state machine that can invoke another state machine. I tried to use following approach to get ARN. However this returns error Arn is not a valid property, which stack is being created.

```
  ParentStateMachine:
    Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
    Properties:
      StateMachineName: !Sub "ParentStateMachine"
      DefinitionString:
        Fn::Sub:
         - |-
            {
              "Comment": "...",
              "StartAt": "State1",
              "States": {
                "State1": {
                  "Type": "Task",
                  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
                  "Parameters": {
                    "StateMachineArn": "${ChildStateMachineArn}",
                    "Input": {
                      "StatePayload": {
                        "datasetDate.$": "$.datasetDate"
                      },
                      "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
                    }
                  },
                  "End": true
                }
              }
            }
         -  {
               ChildStateMachineArn:
                 Fn::GetAtt:
                   - ChildStateMachine
                   - Arn
            }
      RoleArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - StatesExecutionRole
          - Arn
```

I've also tried to generate ARN by using this string.

```
arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:ChildStateMachine
```

However, this gave error

```
Failed to call Step Functions for request: 'com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.model.CreateStateMachineRequest'. (Service: null; Status Code: 500; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
```

I'm able to create other type of state machines using cloud formation. Only when I'm trying to create one that executes a child workflow is not working. When I go to cloud trail, the CreateStateMachineEvent has an error code of Access Denied. I've given Admin Access to the role. Did anyone face this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For States using the "Wait For callback" patterns (those ending in .sync or .waitForTaskToken) you need special policies, as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/service-integration-iam-templates.html).

Specifically in your case, in addition to the Standard *states:StartEecution* policy you need to add event-related policies:

- *events:PutTargets*
- *events:PutRule*
- *events:DescribeRule*

And policies dedicated to the Description and Stopping of the execution:

- *states:DescribeExecution*
- *states:StopExecution*

Details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/stepfunctions-iam.html)

For simplicity, most of the time I use the next policies:

```
  - PolicyName: StatesStartExecutionPolicy
     - PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "states:*"
            Resource: "*"
    - PolicyName: StatesAccessEventsPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "events:*"
            Resource: "*"
```

Comment: I figured out the same thing before I saw your answer when I came back to post the solution. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same issue. I was able to fix after giving the "states:StartExecution" permission to ParentStateMachine.

Create an inline policy for your Parent StatMachine's StatesExecutionRole and add something like below with the ChildStateMachineName. It should fix the issue.

```
- PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - 
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - states:StartExecution
                Resource: !GetAtt ChildStateMachine.Arn
```

Comment: This does work, but for using .sync, we need to add events related accesses as well, as specified in the other answer. But +1 for partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using AWS SAM, you can use an inline policy statement like this:

```
      Policies:
        - StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy:
            StateMachineName: !GetAtt ChildStepFunction.Name
        - Statement:
          - Sid: StatesStartExecutionPolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "states:*"
            Resource: '*'
          - Sid: StatesAccessEventsPolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "events:*"
            Resource: '*'
```